# Django - No module named reportlab.pdfgen

Tags: python, django, importerror

I have ran the following to make sure reportlab is installed. However, Django still give me an exception said reportlab cannot imported.

```
pip install reportlab

>> python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
>>> from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
```

but Django still givingme an error

```
No module named reportlab.pdfgen

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    https://local/p/m/
Django Version:     1.8.11
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named reportlab.pdfgen
```

and follow is my code.

```
def create_pdf(project, matrix, request=None):
        from django.utils import timezone
        from io import BytesIO
        from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
        from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

        y = 700

        buffer = BytesIO()

        p = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=letter)

        p.setFont('Helvetica', 10)
```

Comment: How have you deployed Django? Is it using a different virtual environment to the one you used to test the import in the shell?

Comment: most likely your reportlab is not installed by the same python that runs your django

Comment: I am NOT using virtual env, and I am NOT using a differnt python that runs Django.

Comment: Yeah, I was using virtual env. That fixed it.